# Android ListFragment doesn't save the bundle in onSaveInstanceState()/doesn't retrieve bundle in onActivityCreated()

Tags: android, bundle, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments, screen-orientation

I'm new to android and I'm facing the following problem. I'm developing for both, Android 2 and 3, and this is why I use fragments. However to make the app working on Android 2 devices I import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment. I need to maintain selection within my ListFragment when orientation of the screen changes. I'm overriding `onSaveInstanceState()` method and put an int into the bundle. When the screen is rotated, this method is called and the int is added to the bundle. However when `onActivityCreated()` is called, its bundle is null. I am following the example provided on Android website: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html, but as mentioned above - after `onSaveInstanceState()` is called, the bundle in `onActivityCreated()` is still null.

Here's the code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
public class VisitsHomeFragment extends ListFragment {
    private int selectedPosition = -1;  

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
          if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("SELECTED_POSITION")) {
                selectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("SELECTED_POSITION");
          }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("SELECTED_POSITION", selectedPosition);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: onRestoreInstanceState() is not available for fragments.

Comment: My only suggesting is to debug the compat sources to see if you can get a handle on what's going on.

Comment: You could try adding a logging statement to see if onSaveInstanceState is being called at all. I seem to be having the same problem and as far as I can tell it's never even being called. Something like Log.d("TEST", "onSaveInstanceState called!"); at the end of your onSaveInstanceState should be able to tell you whether or not it's being called.

Comment: As I mentioned in my first post, `onSavaInstanceState()` is called, I checked it. The bundle is being lost like at the Heathrow Airport :-)

Comment: I played with the sample project (HoneycombGallery), added Compatibility Library to it and everything worked just fine... In my app - it doesn't. The temporary solution for me was to add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to the Manifest, but it doesn't solve the mystery of the lost bundle (actually thinking of writing an andventure book entitled "The Mystery of the Lost Bundle" ;-) ).

Comment: In your test was the same version of the compat lib being used? I'm using r1 and briefly updated to r2 but there was at least one bug that I found with onDestroy not being called for a fragment when it was replaced.

Comment: Yes, the same. Imported it from my project to the sample project.

Comment: Hi Maria, I have written almost identical code to you here. Since reading about the issues here I have opted to persist my 'selected spot index' using Shared Preferences and circumvent the fragment saving approach all together. I'm adding the index ```onPause``` and retrieving the value ````onActivityCreated````. Thanks for your good question on this- gave me confidence that I had to go about this another way.

Comment: Do u have a solution for this yet?

Comment: Hi, we actually started locking the orientation of the entire app, so I haven't really been looking at this for ages...

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, adding `android:id` to the fragment element in the layout file fixed this issue.

It seems `FragmentManager` uses the id to send the appropriate bundle when recreating a fragment.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as Maria, and I do have `android:id` defined for the `fragment` element in my layout file. This might be a compatibility library bug.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're not calling `setRetainInstance(true)` in the `Fragment`.  After a little experimentation I pinpointed this as being the error in my code.  The downside of having to do it this way is one has to manually bundle all instance data.

After removing the method call and updating my `onSaveInstanceState` to parcel all of my instance variables, I can now restore list position on rotation.

Comment: If you setRetainInstance(true) then you don't need a bundle at all... The Fragment object is never destroyed and all its variable stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I eventually tracked it down to having different android:id attribute values on the fragment elements in the two different layouts (portrait and landscape).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunatelly it's not the same problem in my case.